# Does 'xinput list' 'Virtual core pointer's id is always '2'?

Tags: 14.04, xinput

Hi I'm newbie to Ubuntu.

I need to know Virtual core pointer Id to use in shell file (`.sh` extension) Chrome. I used command `--touch-devices=2` it is working fine. But I am not sure Virtual core pointer value will be always 2. (I know actual hardware device id will vary as `Logitech Optical USB Mouse id=9` will not necessarily be always 9.)

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)]
⎜ ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ Logitech Optical USB Mouse id=9 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad id=11 [slave pointer (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

I want to use generic command as

```sh
<some_command> --touch-devices=$(xinput --list --id-only 'Virtual core pointer')
```

but it's not working.

Please suggest how should I approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I figured out what to do:

```sh
xinput --list
xinput --list| grep "Virtual core pointer"
xinput --list| grep "Virtual core pointer" | awk '{print $5}'
xinput --list| grep "Virtual core pointer" | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d= -f2
```

So, your answer is:

```sh
<some_command> --touch-devices=$(xinput --list| grep "Virtual core pointer" | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d= -f2)
```

Pipes are fun, but it would be better to just use `awk` for the tasks, that `grep` and `cut` are supposed to do:

```sh
<some_command> --touch-devices=$(xinput --list | awk '/Virtual core pointer/ { print(substr($5, 4)); exit; }')
```

Good programming practice! Determine the number from what the system tells you is true NOW, rather than hard-coding a number that was right once-upon-a-time.

Comment: Even with --touch-devices=$(xinput --list| grep "Virtual core pointer" | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d= -f2) no luck :(

Does 'xinput list' 'Virtual core pointer's id is always '2'? or does it vary?

Comment: What is "No luck :(" supposed to tell us? Have you tried the series of commands in the answer? Which one fails? Since the command string works for me, I have to ask if `--touch-devices=2` is "lucky"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, even terminal command   `xinput --list | awk '/Virtual core pointer/ { print(substr($5, 4)); exit; }' ` on my pc produces result 2. But I'm using this code in .sh shell script . (running above script doesn't produce same effect as assigning 2 directly as ( `--touch-devices=2`). May be i need to cast `$(xinput --list | awk '/Virtual core pointer/ { print(substr($5, 4)); exit; }')` to integer or how should I do?

Comment: Try using `/bin/bash`, rather than `/bin/sh`, if you can.

Comment: I think the problem is : I'm using  `xinput --list | awk '/Virtual core pointer/ { print(substr($5, 4)); exit; }'' ` inside openbox-session and openbox is not able to run `$ xinput --list `?
Is there anyway I could run `~$ xinput --list` in openbox mode?

Comment: I got desired result with the following :
'--touch-devices=`echo $(xinput list | grep 'Virtual core pointer' | awk 'match(\$0, /id=/){print substr($0, RSTART+3, RLENGTH-1)}')`